# Getting hudson.remoting.ChannelClosedException at Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy

At my company we are using `CommandLauncher` class to connect the slaves. We ran the connection script with `CommandLauncher launcher = new CommandLauncher("/var/jenkins_home/workspace/Infra/build-scripts/launch-slave.sh $ip")`, and it worked like magic.

Since we upgraded our Jenkins and now we have to use the script approval, we can't use it this way cause we don't want to approve every time a new node is joining. So we are passing the IP as environment variable so the script will run without any approve, like this:

```
CommandLauncher launcher = new CommandLauncher(
      "/var/jenkins_home/workspace/Infra/build-scripts/launch-slave.sh",
      new EnvVars("NODE_IP", ip)
  )
```

The `launch-slave.sh` is doing the same only uses the IP as environment variable. It's important to understand that the script is identically the same.

Since then we are getting `hudson.remoting.ChannelClosedException: Channel "unknown": Remote call on 192.168.148.202 failed. The channel is closing down or has closed down` errors that never happened before, and we are sure cause we changed the script back and we don't see it. Only when it takes the IP from EnvVars we this behaviour, which we do not understand how this minor change can cause this disconnections.

Comment: getting same error, dont know how to do connection between windows10 master and centos (slave) ping and ssh works but launch agent gets failed same error which you facing,